# Jackson ObjectWriter write including ignored fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

Let's say I have some field of the class annotated with `@JsonIgnore`:

```
public TestClass{
  @JsonIgnore TestField fild;
}
```

But now I want to write the object of this class to json including these fields. How can I do this? Is there some property to use with `ObjectMapper`, something like `objectMapper.properties(INCLUDE_IGNORED_FIELDS).write(object)` or something like this?

Comment: It's possible to disable all annotations, see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations. You can do that for specific `ObjectMapper` instances. If needed you can clone an existing one to disable the feature. Another option is to switch it around - don't ignore by default, and add ignores when you need them. You can do the latter using mix-ins. Those are somewhat explained on the same site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using this:

```
    objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
    String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
```